# Android webview imprimir

Tags: android, webview

He creado una app que es un `webview` que abre una página web hecha en **`PHP`** en android como si fuera una aplicación, funciona perfectamente pero el problema es que los botones de imprimir no funcionan, les das y no hacen nada y si entras por google chrome en android funcionan totalmente, no se si es que en un webview no se puede o que falta importar algo o crear algún objteto para poder imprimir.

El código sería:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("la url");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    WebView mWebView;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Comment: Hola @LuisAlfonsoZ, te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a la guía de como realizar preguntas [Guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Es necesario que muestres el código que tienes para que te podamos ayudar y poder ayudarte a resolver dónde está el error. Un saludo

Comment: hola pudiste imprimir con un boton el webview?
ya que e tenido el mismo problema o si alguien a encontrado solucion a esto

Answer (score -1):

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) aparece bien claro las limitaciones del [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) a la hora de imprimir documentos:

- No puede agregar encabezados o pies de página, incluidos los números
  de página, al documento.
- Las opciones de impresión del documento HTML
  no incluyen la posibilidad de imprimir rangos de páginas, por
  ejemplo: No se admite la página 2 a 4 de un documento HTML de 10
  páginas.
- Una instancia de WebView sólo puede procesar un trabajo de
  impresión a la vez.
- No se admite un documento HTML que contenga
  atributos de impresión CSS, como las propiedades en modo apaisado.
- **No puede utilizar JavaScript en un documento HTML para activar la impresión.**

En la misma documentación podrás ver como imprimir desde Android. Podrás hacerlo mediante un botón desde tu app.